# Restricting form input goes haywire

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to restrict form input in a form that I have. The particular input is for an ID that has very specific requirements. An example of which would be:

YY.MM.DD-000.00

The code I'm working with to restrict it is:

```
<form>

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="nid"
                       name="nid" placeholder="@lang('app.nid')"
     pattern="[00-99]{2}+\.[00-12]{2}\.[00-31]{2}+\-[000-999]{3}+\.[00-99]{2}"
                       title="YY.MM.DD-000.00"
                       value="" />
<button type="submit">
submit
</button>   
</form>
```

And I can't seem to make it accept it. It seems refuses any input I give, both the bad and the supposibly good.

Can anyone help me figure out why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of those `+` in your regex. Not sure what you want there, but if you remove those it works. Those plus signs make your regex invalid.

Another problem was the `-` you escaped. This caused the regex not to work as well:

```
pattern="[00-99]{2}\.[00-12]{2}\.[00-31]{2}-[000-999]{3}\.[00-99]{2}"
```

Comment: Note that the character groups can be simplified and are incorrect for the months and the days. The month for example only allows the numbers `[0-2]` so no March through September.

Comment: Thank you for your input but sadly this doesn't seem to work for me. It will allow any input without errors. Is there anyway I can check why that is?

Comment: @user5740843 "thanks for the input, here is a downvote". That's nice.... Anyways, the other problem was that you escaped the `-`. I've updated my answer accordingly

Comment: I don't see how this could work for days or months with the numbers 2/3/4 to 9 in them...

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstand how character groups `[...]` work in regexes: They define the characters that you can input so you don't need to repeat them and when you use them for months and days, you do need the higher numbers as well as you will not be able to input `09` for example (September or day 9 of the month).

So you need:

```
[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{2}
```

Note that I have also removed the `+` quantifiers and I am not escaping the `-` as that is only a special character in a character group. However, it works both with and without these.

You can see it [here](https://regex101.com/r/gu3SPq/1).

Comment: You are right that my answer, which is basically his pattern but without errors, doesn't completely satisfy his case. The problem with yours is that it also allows months > 12 and dates > 31. Obviously a normal date regexp would be better here. The regex works inside `regex101`, but `html` uses a more stricter syntax

Comment: @PierreDuc I agree, personally I'd probably go for a separate datepicker and number input and do the real validation on the server side.